# Use of definite article (ה) in יהי רצון ... מצות התלוים

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

The paragraph after the ברכה (*b'racha*) of ציצת (*tzitzis*) ends with the expression " וְתַרְיַ"ג מִצְות הַתְּלוּיִם בָּהּ".

My question is why does the word "התלוים" start with "ה"? It appears like the "תלוים" is part of a definite noun phrase.

> יְהִי רָצון מִלְּפָנֶיךָ. ה' אֱלהַי וֵאלהֵי אֲבותַי. שֶׁתְּהֵא חֲשׁוּבָה מִצְוַת צִיצִית לְפָנֶיךָ כְּאִלּוּ קִיַּמְתִּיהָ בְּכָל פְּרָטֶיהָ וְדִקְדּוּקֶיהָ וְכַוָּנותֶיהָ. וְתַרְיַ"ג מִצְות הַתְּלוּיִם בָּהּ. אָמֵן סֶלָה

(["Da'at Sidur Ashk'naz"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Tzitzit_(**Includes_Yehi_Ratzon)?lang=he))

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, Hebrew is my mother tongue.

1. ה is frequently used as ש (which) in Hebrew, meaning מצוות שתלויות etc. For example we say "הנותן ליעף כח", meaning "שנותן ליעף כח" because the original verse is without ה at all.
2. Another reason is that in medieval (and Mishnaic) Hebrew this form is also frequent like שבת הגדול, and the contemporary proper Hebrew form would be definitely המצוות התלויות.
   BTW the fact that is does not align gender (should read מצוות התלויות) just proves it is a mistake.

Comment: שבת הגדול  may be in the construct from - the shabbat of [haftarat] 'Hagadol' (לפני בוא יום ה' הגדול והנורא)

Comment: @JoelK BTW the fact that it does not align gender proves it's a mistake

Comment: Are you talking about shabbat hagadol?

Comment: 1. Do you have a source for this? I believe in various strata of Hebrew including modern that ה prefix on the second word is still the definite article in form and function. 2. I'm not sure what the context of the paragraph in the question is, but if the words preceding the word מצות comprise a number, couldn't that be a type of definite quantifier as well, obviating the need for the article?

Comment: >>@JoelK BTW the fact that it does not align gender proves it's a mistake. >>Would a mistake in the siddur not be corrected over time?

Comment: @WAF I'm a native Hebrew speaker, 1 I added sources, 2 no it's not. You can't say in Hebrew תפוח האדום you have to use two ה (like in English you say "The red apple" but not "the red the apple").

Comment: I don't follow what you say in #1. To me, it seems that you are referring to the "person" that gives the strength. Frequently, in Hebrew, verbs are used as nouns. It seems that in the bracha, it means "The one who gives strength to the tired."

Comment: One translation of #2 is "The Shabbat of the 'Gadol'" (meaning, the Shabbat of the rav. The rav spoke only twice yearly, oin Shabbat Shuva and the Shabbat before Pesach (Hagadol.) Thus, using the *heh* here is correct as it is possessive. (Similar to *Sefer Ha'ish* - "The man's book".)

Comment: @DanF "The one that"  is exactly that, ש meant "that..."

Comment: Possibly, within this context. Usually, the noun is much closer to the verb in such cases. But, in this case, using ש seems like it would work. Though, I think there's a slight nuance in the meaning using the *heh* over here.